# How to center part of object in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, image-alignment

I would like to know how to center a part of object to the center of the screen in Photoshop.

Here is an example photo - cell phone with antenna: 
[image]

The cellphone and it's antenna is selected as one object and it's in custom layer. Now I would like to **align the cell phone's body (without antenna) to the center of the image**.

Is it possible to do this somehow in Photoshop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is almost certainly a better way than this, but since I don't have Photoshop in front of me, the first thing that comes to mind is to make a duplicate layer that has only the cellphone body.  Align that to the center and then position the original layer in the same position.  I will update my answer when I get home and have a chance to look for a more direct approach.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is there some function to automatically set layer's position to the same position as another layer (same X,Y)? Or do I have to move the layer manually to see where they "cross"?

Comment: @JoudicekJouda - unfortunately it would be manual since the layers aren't the same size, so the x/y position won't be the same.  I also wasn't able to figure out an easier way to do it after taking a look.  There might still be one, but I couldn't figure it out if there is.